# Flickering laptop screen when hot - cause?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu, cable, laptop-display

*What could be the cause of a flickering screen every minute or so    like the picture below?*

- Flickering seems to get worse when hot (usually into an hour of
  gaming CPU 100C, GPU 85C max).
- Adjusting the laptop screen or even tapping the laptop while
  flickering stops it.
- I recently disconnected and reconnected all the circuits in the
  laptop for cleaning.
- Laptop is a bit more than 3 years old (Acer Aspire v3-471G).

I am hoping the cause is due to loose cable connection not GPU. I think that's likely as my laptop also flickers when I am in Desktop ie even when not using the NVIDIA GPU (it has integrated intel too).

If that is true then the problem is how to open the laptop up again because an important screw has lost its grip...

[image: Picture of Similar Flickering Screen]

Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: Screen still flickering when at 55C (normal temp)

EDIT2: Adjusting screen when not flickering causes flickering as well if I hit the right 'spot'.

Comment: this is definitely a problem with something other than the GPU, though odd behavior for a loose cable. I'd recommend reseating the connection from the screen to the motherboard just to be sure, though this is likely not the problem. Just a side note: I would recommend keeping your cpu under 90 degrees at all times just to be safe. Maybe invest in a laptop cooling pad.

Comment: if you do ever get the screw out, replace it so you don't have the problem again. Stripped screws can be a pain though

Comment: @Blaine yeah right now I'm thinking of a way to remove the screw without damaging my laptop... :(

Comment: if you're desperate, an interesting solution would be to try to superglue a screwdriver to the screw and see if it's strong enough to turn and twist it out after letting it harden.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea, I'll try it when I get some superglue haha

Comment: @user9856 [What are your tips/tricks for removing or extracting stripped screws?](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/7393/What+are+your+tips-tricks+for+removing+or+extracting+stripped+screws) and [removing a mini stripped screw on a laptop?!?!](http://www.doityourself.com/forum/hardware-fasteners/218198-removing-mini-stripped-screw-laptop.html)

Answer (score 2):

For the readers in the future. About 5 years ago (2015) I had the same problem with my 5 years old n5110 core i7 with a powerful gpu both on the same heatsink.

It is absolutely your thermal grease or thermal pads. They are not transferring the heat well. Thermal greases will not lose their natural chemical effect during time but they get stoned and stone is easily fragile making nano threads of insulating air by any tiny shocks.

I'm still using my 10years old n5110 for software development and gaming.

The important note is : the thermal pads can be torn easily when we loose and fasten a heatsink again (they lose their shape by pressure like a memory foam) thus even if CPU and GPU are greased well the motherboard's chipsets may be hot too.